Error with GeoServer: "The specified dimensional parameter is non-positive" when scale not 1 in SLD
I'm using a custom SLD style to render surface currents with GeoServer vesrion 2.20.3. This SLD structure works fine for other layers in order to display arrows. But for this perticular set of GeoTIFF files, I get the following error when  using my style on the layer.

Caused by: org.geotools.process.ProcessException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified dimensional parameter is non-positive.
at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:649)
at org.geotools.process.function.ProcessFunction.evaluate(ProcessFunction.java:154)
... 131 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified dimensional parameter is non-positive.
at javax.media.jai.ImageLayout.setTileWidth(ImageLayout.java:548)
at javax.media.jai.ImageLayout.(ImageLayout.java:208)
at it.geosolutions.jaiext.utilities.ImageLayout2.(ImageLayout2.java:112)
at org.geotools.image.ImageWorker.scale(ImageWorker.java:4460)
at org.geotools.image.ImageWorker.affine(ImageWorker.java:4368)
at org.geotools.coverage.processing.operation.Affine.createRenderedImage(Affine.java:116)
at org.geotools.coverage.processing.BaseScaleOperationJAI.deriveGridCoverage(BaseScaleOperationJAI.java:188)
at org.geotools.coverage.processing.OperationJAI.doOperation(OperationJAI.java:302)
at org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessor.doOperation(CoverageProcessor.java:575)
at org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessor.doOperation(CoverageProcessor.java:598)
at org.geotools.process.raster.AffineProcess.execute(AffineProcess.java:128)
at org.geotools.process.raster.RasterAsPointCollectionProcess.execute(RasterAsPointCollectionProcess.java:155)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor408.invoke(Unknown Source)
at

After some digging, I think I found the problematic part of the SLD. In the Transformation section, I use the wms_scale_denominator to change the scale value depending on the zoom level:
     <Transformation>
      <ogc:Function name="ras:RasterAsPointCollection">
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>interpolation</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>InterpolationBilinear</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
            <ogc:Function name="env">
              <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>200000</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>10000000</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
    </Transformation>

I found out that the error occurs whenever the scale value is different from 1. What is causing this problem is what I do not know. My GeoTIFF seems to be constructed well. Here is the gdalinfo:

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ciops-east_2024-04-09-06.tif
Size is 1333, 978
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
CS[ellipsoidal,2],
AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
ORDER[1],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
ORDER[2],
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
USAGE[
SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
AREA["World."],
BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-77.000000000000000,54.439999999999998)
Pixel Size = (0.029977494373593,-0.019979550102249)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=LZW
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -77.0000000,  54.4400000) ( 77d 0' 0.00"W, 54d26'24.00"N)
Lower Left  ( -77.0000000,  34.9000000) ( 77d 0' 0.00"W, 34d54' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( -37.0400000,  54.4400000) ( 37d 2'24.00"W, 54d26'24.00"N)
Lower Right ( -37.0400000,  34.9000000) ( 37d 2'24.00"W, 34d54' 0.00"N)
Center      ( -57.0200000,  44.6700000) ( 57d 1'12.00"W, 44d40'12.00"N)
Band 1 Block=1333x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=1333x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined

I'm having a hard time figuring out the meaning of the error The specified dimensional parameter is non-positive in that situation.
Any ideas?
